# I want to covert this string (Mon, 30th Nov 2020 08:54 PM) to 30-11-2020 date format in JavaScript, please help me out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using php laravel blade file there i would like to convert this string (Mon, 30th Nov 2020 08:54 PM) to 30-11-2020 , is this possible, if it, please help me out

Comment: Do you mean Date formatting in javascript or jquery?

Comment: any of these, thanks for your replay though my problem solved by below answer, but if you have any great solution then please post here, I will also learn from it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let originalString = "Mon, 30th Nov 2020 08:54 PM";
let newString = originalString.split(', ')[1].substr(0, originalString.length - 3).replace("th", "");

let date = new Date(newString);
let newDateString = `${date.getDate()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getFullYear()}`;
console.log(newDateString);
```